# Word to describe a subject where people learn how to do work?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Is there a word to describe a subject where people learn how to do work?

For example, "I'm in a class called  where we learn how to manage our time, plan work, write various documents, and present work."

I'm interested if there is a single word for this (but I'm also open to multi-word options).

Business didn't seem right because the things described are general skills that can be applied to more than business. I've heard of "life skills" courses, but that seemed too personal/ too much like a "home ec" type description.

Comment: Here are some common terms: study skills, time management, work flow, career exploration, career building skills, office management skills.  Stay away from "life skills" because that is a common term for non-inclusive classes for high school students with low cognition.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description I would consider calling it a *Career Skills* or *Professional Skills* course.

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: I would call it 'study skills'.

Comment: Hm yeah could be better. I’m unclear from the original post if by “work” the asker means professional work or course work.

Answer (score 1):

Vocational, perhaps? The definition is to undergo training in a skill or trade which is anticipated to prepare one for a specific job or employment opportunity

I think this nearly precisely matches what I think you’re looking for? Although, there is always a chance that I’be misread... if this is the case, is there any more information or clarification you could provide by chance?